# Code Blocks - wx/setup: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I'm trying to write my first cpp program on Windows+Code Blocks.

I've installed wxwidgets.

I have a label and a button.

When I hit F9, I get the error: **error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory**.

The error is highlighted on the file platform.h at line 196 which contains **#include "wx/setup.h"**

I did a search for the file on my hdd. It is in **c:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\wx\msw** and some other locations as well.

When I change the line 196 to **wx/msw/setup.h** this error is gone but there are other errors.

I think I'm missing on something really elementary but also vital. Any thoughts please... Thanks!

EDIT: I don't know if this matters but when I start a new wxwidgets project I get the following screen:
[image]
And then I continue clicking yes.

Comment: Try Settings->Compiler and Debugger->Search Directories and add C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\wx\msw. Not having done anything important, I've always just copy-pasted any extra headers into my C::B directory, so I'm not sure if it'll work, but it looks like it should.

Comment: @chris thank you for the inputs... But I still have the same issue. When I change the include path to "wx/msw/setup.h" this error is gone but others pop up. I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: I just downloaded wxWidgets and compiled `#include <setup.h> int main(){}` successfully (using my last suggestion, which worked :p). What other code do you have and what errors does it give?

Comment: @chris I only started a new project using wxWidgets and added one label and one command button. Nothing else. Then when I compile, a file named platform.h shows up with the error on the line that states include "wx/setup.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which GUI builder you have selected while creating project. I think this error occurs due to incorrect selection of GUI builder. For your project select

> wxformBuilder

in prefered GUI Builder option and select

> frame based

in application type option. You can follow this link [**here**](http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com/2011/02/setup-wxwidget-in-codeblock.html) which explain to setup every step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It did get my program to work. But I don't understand WHY... If I should select wxFormBuilder, then why do they offer a choice of wxSmith as well...?

Comment: I am also unknown about this.

Answer (score 1):

It is now 2016 and most of the above are 2012 so probably earlier versions of Code::Blocks or Widgets, but I found it was whenever I didn't have 'enable unicode' selected it gave the no Setup.h file error. With 'enable unicode' selected there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I haven't used Code::Blocks in a while but I want to get back to it sometime. Could you please indicate in your answer, where the unicode setting is done? I don't recall the interface - sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem experienced.

I solved the problem by including the wxWidgets's include and lib folder in the global variables[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's now 2023 and still, I don't think the right solution has been posted here or in any other similar threads.

Here's what wiki.wxwidgets.org said:

> Under some circumstances, while compiling on multiple cores, you may
> receive compilation error at the very beginning about missing setup.h
> file. To overcome this issue, generate this file first with
> **setup_h** tag at the end of build parameters:
>
> `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release setup_h`

You can see the full documentation here:

https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW#Build_the_library